# Measure theory question: Show that for $1<p<\infty, l^1(\mathbb N)\subset l^p(\mathbb N)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am having trouble trying to prove this containement for lp spaces: $l^1(\mathbb N) \subset l^p(\mathbb N)$. 
Initially, I was thinking of choosing some sequence from L1 and show it is in Lp but didn't how to proceed with the proof.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well $f\in l^1(\mathbb{N})$ means that $\int |f| d\mu= \sum_{n=1}^\infty
 |f(n)|<\infty$. Since the series converges then there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies that $|f(n)|\leq 1$. As $p\geq 1$, then for all $n\geq N$ we have that $|f(n)|^p\leq |f(n)|$. Hence $\sum_{n\geq N}|f(n)|^p\leq \sum_{n\geq N} |f(n)| < \infty
$. Clearly $|f(n)|<\infty$ for any $n$, so $\sum_{n=1}^N|f(n)|^p <\infty
$. It follows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty
|f(n)|^p < \infty
$, hence $f\in l^p(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: $\sum_{n\geq N}|f(n)|^p\leq \sum_{n\geq N}\leq f(n) < \infty$ what is this isolated sum after $\sum_{n\geq N}|f(n)|^p$?

Comment: its just ∑n≥N |f(n)|

Answer (score 1):

For $(a_n)\in l^1$, $|a_n|$ is clearly bounded, say the bound is $M$.

Then $\sum |a_n|^p \le M^{p-1}\sum|a_n| < \infty$

BTW, show you thought instead of just put the question next time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a converging series $(a_n)$. From some $n$ onwards the $|a_n| \leqq 1$, so by taking the $p$:th power the series converges even faster. Before that $n$ there are only finite number of elements, so they don't matter on the convergence issue.